# Sum a dataFrame column based on value of another column meeting a certain criteria

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data in two columns [A and B].  I'd like to sum the data in Column B if the value in column A is less than zero.

I tried to iterate over the DF but this just becomes clunky.  So I tried the below:

```
DF_AB['A' < 0] = DF_AB.B.sum()
```

But this isn't great because it's not even doing anything.  It just says if A < 0 then sum B but it doesn't assign it to anything.  Trying to stick to Pandas here.  Any thoughts appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Df_ab[df_ab['A'] < 0].B.sum() ?

Comment: can you show us your sample data ?

Comment: @QuangHoang got it correct.  That works.  Thank you.